# Testflight can not find the SDK in Mac OS X desktop app?

Tags: ios, macos, api, sdk, testflight

I am trying to create an add hoc version over the desktop app of Test FLight but it fails to find the sdk?

[image]

Comment: Did you import the TestFlight Framework to you project? What iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: i have 10.7.4 and i imported the SDK to project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there are some issues with the TestFlight client since the 1.1 SDK update, which add support for ARMv7s (iPhone 5). I had exactly the same issue.

You can still upload your builds using the web-interface. Everything works there, so **better to wait for a client app update**.

To upload a build, from xCode, go to the **Organizer** (cmd-shift-2), and select **"Archives"**.

Select the archive you need to upload, and click **"Distribute"**.

Select **"Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc deployment"**, and select your signing identity.

You'll then be able to save the **ipa** file, that you can upload using the TestFlight web interface.

Comment: how can i make sure if i upload over web interface that the sdk is also included and i could track the crash reports?

Comment: You'll be able to see the SDK version used in the build from the TestFlight web-interface.

Comment: and sometimes when i upload the api from desktop app the testers do not get even notified even the file is successfully uploaded so it is really better to use web interface